# Parse information from an email

Tags: c#, parsing

My goal is to gather information from an email and remove everything except for some key information, in this case a name.

Below is a sample email that is received. I have been able to pull the email from Outlook and load all of the body text into a datagrid but I'm not sure how to parse through the information and retrieve the first and last name information.

**Text version**

```
From: Company
Sent: Sunday, May 7, 2017 Eastern Time (US & Canada)
To: LastName, FirstName (CompanyName)
Subject: Thank you for your recent purchase.

Dear FirstName LastName,
Thank you for
```

**HTML Version**

```
<font face="Tahoma" size="2"><b>From:</b> Company<br>
<b>Sent:</b> Sunday, May 7, 2017(UTC-05:00) Eastern Time (US &amp; Canada)<br>
<b>To:</b> LastName, FirstName (CompanyName)<br>
<b>Subject:</b> Thank you for your recent purchase<br>
<font face="Tahoma" size="2"><b>From:</b> Company<br>
<b>Sent:</b> Sunday, May 7, 2017(UTC-05:00) Eastern Time (US &amp; Canada)<br>
<b>To:</b> LastName, FirstName (CompanyName)<br>
<b>Subject:</b> Thank you for your recent purchase<br>
</font><br>
<div></div>
<div>
<div id="left-align-on-reply" dir="ltr">
<div id="main">
<div id="logo-row-box" style="width:95%; text-align:right; padding-top:6%; padding-bottom:6%">
<img id="imagesent" src="image.png" style="display:inline-block; height:28px; width:24px; right:0px">
</div>
<table id="message-body-wrapper" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td id="message-body-left-margin" width="0"></td>
<td id="message-body">
<table id="paragraphs" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="paragraph" style="padding:0 5% 18px; font:300 14px/18px 'Lucida Grande',Lucida Sans,Lucida Sans Unicode,sans-serif,Arial,Helvetica,Verdana,sans-serif; color:#333">
Dear FirstName LastName,</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some ugly RegEx to the rescue

```
var regex = new Regex("To:</b> ([A-z]+), ([A-z]+)");
var m = regex.Match(GetHtml());
var firstName = m.Groups[2].Value;
var secondName = m.Groups[1].Value;
```

Please note that this is quite brittle and only works for english letters the way it is defined.

Edit: Breakdown of the regex as requested

- `"To:</b> "` is the pattern the string of characters we are looking for has to start with.
- `"([A-z]+),"` then looks for one or more of the characters between A and z (both upper and lower case) before a comma. Note that this does not handle double names, names with hyphens or any characters beyond this. The () surrounding it captures the result in a group.
- `" ([A-z]+)"` works the same way for the first name coming after the comma

Comment: This answer did the trick. I'm trying to learn a bit of Regex since it seems to easily handle a lot of situations that I've come across. Could you give a breakdown of what is happening in the first line?

Comment: Updated the answer with some details